# Connect to server via SSH2

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, connection

I'm using http://www.hetzner.de/en/. 
They send me something like that:

```
Your Hetzner-Server is now active. Thank you for choosing Hetzner Online as your Web Hosting partner.

You can access your server immediately via SSH2, using following details:

IP-Address: *.*.*.*
Login:      "login"
Password:   "password"
```

So, I'm trying to connect to this server in this way:

```
ssh login@*.*.*.*
```

Then I input my password, but it gives an error "permission denied".

Can anyone tel me why and how can I fix this?

Comment: I'm sorry I have to ask but, are you sure you entered the credentials correctly? Normally this should be the way you log in.

Comment: it's probably worth to remind that credentials are case sensitive ..
avoid copy-pasting you may be pasting some extra caracters

Comment: Running ssh -v might provide additional clues. Also feel free to try -vv as well as -vvv.

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin, yes, I'm sure.

Comment: You should probably direct this question to your hosting providers tech support. You should also read our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Windows, using PuTTY:
Try opening the event log. You can get to it by right-clicking the titlebar of an active PuTTY window.

If you're on Linux, try `ssh -v` (or more v's), as comments to your question suggest.

Finally, if you're 100% sure you didn't mistype, and didn't copy paste (in the age of rich-text clipboards, that's a bad idea), you can always send their support an email.

Comment: I think this is the perfect answer, couldn't have put it better myself